# How to display detailed view activity inside Fragment on image button click

Tags: android, fragment

I am moving my code from Activity to use it under Fragment view. The grid has multiple images which gets successfully displayed inside the fragment.I am trying to display detailed view based on the image clicked. But I am unable to get to do this, tried different ways but resulting one or other error.Earlier I used to have setContentView which does not seem to work when used for Fragment. I am already inflating the Fragment under OnCreateView method but not sure how load with the detailed view upon the image click.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(view.getContext(), iconSize);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             //setContentView(R.layout.list_item_main);


            mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list_view);
            Item.getRecipesFromDB(OneFragment.this, DBReference);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(mListView.getContext(), itemList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a new Fragment when a gridView is clicked and then pass the position from the bundle parameters. Then in NewFragment show the listview and the data from database.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("POSITION",position);
            this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag,TAG_FRAGMENT)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

In the NextFragment get the reference of listView and then update the data from database using proper adapter.

Comment: I have tried as suggested but results in error :java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView                                                             `ListItemMainFragment nextFrag = new ListItemMainFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("POSITION",position);
                OneFragment.this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.grid, nextFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();`

Comment: ` @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, container, false);
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_list_view);
      
        final String DBReference = "all/0/Doctors";
        Item.getRecipesFromDB(ListItemMainFragment.this, DBReference);

        return view;
    }`

Comment: `OneFragment.this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.grid, nextFrag) .addToBackStack(null) .commit(); ` change the id from grid to container of the fragment. "R.id.grid "  -> R.id.container

Comment: 'grid' is the id of the container.

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

        CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(view.getContext(), iconSize);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">
    <GridView
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        />
</RelativeLayout>